# How can I enter data into a Sheets like I can with Excel formular?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a large Google sheet with numerous lookup functions etc.
How can I build a mask to make it easier to enter data into the first sheet? The data would have to be at the end of the list on that sheet.
I know it is possible with Excel formular.

Answer (score 0):

go to Insert and insert the Form:

[image: 0]